# Diffuse texture CreateTexture2D fails?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have a 2d diffuse texture loaded into memory and want to create a dx11 texture from it. It does not need to be altered so I made it immutable.

```
DX11Texture::DX11Texture(ID3D11Device* device, const std::vector<uint8_t>& textureData, uint32_t textureWidth, uint32_t textureHeight, TextureType textureType, Logger& logger) :
        mTexture(nullptr), mTextureID(gNextTextureID++)
    {
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
        textureDesc.Width = textureWidth;
        textureDesc.Height = textureHeight;
        textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
        textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
        ZeroMemory(&initData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
        initData.pSysMem = &textureData.at(0);

        DXCALL(device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, &initData, &mTexture));     // throws E_INVALIDARG result
    }
```

I don't see why it is causing a faulty result from the CreateTexture2D call. For example, I have a texture 128x128 R8B8G8A8 texture and it throws a bad result. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably also set the value of `SysMemPitch` member of `initData` as explained here [msdn: d3d11_subresource_data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476220(v=vs.85).aspx). Also keep in mind that `CreateTexture2D` expects a pointer to an array of `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA` (one for each mip level).

Comment: You may want to look at the implementation of DDSTextureLoader in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).